# Como mudar o diretório /wp-admin - sem o plugin WPS Hide

Tags: php, wordpress, sql-update

Galera, bom dia.
 
Preciso trocar a área de administração do meu site wordpress pra fora do wp-admin, criando um outro link com o nome que eu quiser.

O que pega é que não tô afim de curiosos fuçando o site e quero me proteger de ataques brute force comuns, vou criar um link se possível mais complicadinho. Ou seja:

Ao invés de ter isso

```
www.linkdomeusite.com/wp-admin
```

Preciso ter algo como:

```
www.linkdomeusite.com/brftysTyKjh
```

Alguém tem alguma dica? Sabem como fazer isso?

 Eu não tenho acesso ao servidor. O desenvolvedor antigo do site me fez o favor de não atualizar o PHP e nem me disponibilizar acesso.

Quê que eu faço?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bianca, seja bem-vinda ao Stackoverflow!

Antes de mais nada, renomear ou mover o diretório "wp-admin" não é aconselhável pois irá quebrar toda sua aplicação WordPress, já que esse diretório está definido no core do CMS.

Agora, remapear a URL de login para outra é possível adicionando um "filter_action" e criando uma regra no arquivo .htaccess na raíz do sistema. Porém, para isso é necessário ter acesso ao servidor onde o sistema está hospedado.

Como você quer fazer essa alteração por razões de segurança (evitar ataques bruteforce) é bem desnecessário, basta ter um certificado SSL ativo e ter o apoio dos serviços de uma empresa como o Cloudflare, qual com a conta gratuita já é de grande ajuda para evitar esses tipos de ataques.

Comment: Show. Muito obrigada, Cesar!

Comment: Por nada Bianca, tenha um ótimo dia!